# Debounce function not working as expected, as if it's not being executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to avoid using lodash in my project, and I've eliminated everything except this one debounce function. According to [this](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore#_debounce) You-Dont-Need, this debounce should work just fine. But, for some reason, it's not being called.

Here's what I have,

```
import * as React from "react";

export default function DebouncedSearch() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

  const debounce = (
    func: (...params: any[]) => any,
    wait: number,
    immediate = false
  ) => {
    let timeout;

    return function () {
      const later = () => {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func();
      };
      const callNow = immediate && !timeout;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
      if (callNow) func();
    };
  };

  const handleChange = React.useCallback(
    ({ target: { value } }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      debounce(() => {
        setValue(value);
      }, 500);
    },
    []
  );

  return <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[image: nervous-rain-didvm]

## Edit

If I do this,

```
  const handleChange = React.useCallback(
    ({ target: { value } }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      debounce(() => {
        console.log("called");
        setValue(value);
      }, 500)();
    },
    []
  );
```

It prints `called` as many times as the onChange event fires, not once.

Comment: You're not calling the function that debounce returns

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: `debounce(() => {
        setValue(value);
      }, 500)();`

Comment: If I do that, it doesn't debounce the change. If I start typing a lot, it adds many characters, instead of the last one.

Comment: I've edited the OP.

Comment: Is the goal to limit the number of characters the user can type to 1 every 500ms?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this and avoiding render state issues, is to use a `useRef`.

Below I've just used a setInterval, instead of debounce logic, I prefer that to debounce..

But if you prefer debounce, it should be trivial to alter to do it using that instead.

```js
const {useState, useEffect, useRef} = React;


function MyInput() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const v = useRef({value: '', changed:false});
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const i = setInterval(() => {
      if (v.current.changed) {
         console.log('change: ' + v.current.value);
         v.current.changed = false;
      }
    }, 500);
    return () => clearInterval(i);
  }, []);
  
  return <input 
    onChange={(e) => {
      setValue(e.target.value);
      v.current.changed = true;
      v.current.value = e.target.value;
    }}
    value={value}
  />;
}



ReactDOM.render(<MyInput/>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="mount"></div>
```